# Laravel 8 - 'refresh()' on Model do not execute Anonymous Global Scopes

Tags: sql, eloquent, scope, laravel-8

I've defined a simple **Anonymous Global Scopes** (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes) in my Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('mystringScope', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->selectRaw('post.*, CONCAT(post.field1,"--",post.field2) AS mystring');
        });
    }
}
```

when I run the command: `Post::find(1)->toArray()`, the query executed is correct:

```
select post.*, CONCAT(post.field1,"--",post.field2) AS mystring from post where id = 1;
```

and the output returns:

```
array:4 [
  "id" => 2,
  "field1" => "aa",
  "field2" => "bb",
  "mystring" => "aa--bb"
]
```

But when I run a `refresh()` on an existing Model, the query doesn't contain the `scope` condition:

```
$myPost = Post::find(1);
$myPost->refresh();
```

the query is:

```
select * from post where id = 1;
```

Why the `scope` is not executed in `refresh()`?

Thank you

Comment: `refresh` creates a new query without global scopes `static::newQueryWithoutScopes()->findOrFail($this->getKey())...`

Comment: you may want to look into appending an accessor for `mystring` that does this concatenation for you

Comment: Thank you @lagbox for your comment; yes, I know 'accessor' option but I cannot use for all my case; for example to convert a MySQL geometry, I use "scope" adding `AsText(geom) AS geometry` in the query and this is not possibile with 'accessor'. The answer to this question is: "If I use `scope` I cannot use `refresh()` but I must use `find()`".